# Random String matching

Tags: java, string

So I have used the generateRandomChars etc for a string I am providing which looks something like this;

```
System.out.println(generateRandomChars("ABCD", 1)); //Takes 1 random letter.
```

The problem I am having is getting the user to match what is outputted, I have tried it but it still says no even in the character selected is correct. This is the bit I'm stuck on.

```
Scanner a = new Scanner((System.in));
String character = a.nextLine();
if(character.equals(a)){
System.out.println("Yes");
}

else (!character.equals(a)) {
System.out.println("No");
}
}
```

Obviously I am not going to be able to predict which letter is chosen.

Comment: are you sure you want to check if character is equal to scanner :) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to check if the character read from the user is equal to the `Scanner` object (referenced by the variable `a`), which will be always false.

You need to store the letter generated in a variable before printing it :

```
String generated = generateRandomChars("ABCD", 1);
System.out.println(generated);
```

And then, you can actually do the comparison:

```
if (character.equals(generated)) { ... }
```

NB: Make sure generateRandomChars returns a `String`, and not a `Character` instance, though ( "a" is not equal to 'a' in java)

Comment: Ah, that makes a little more sense, thanks for the help!